Set setsar=sar=1/1, for all video streams/FFMPEG
I encountered the problem that I can't set setsar=sar=1/1 on all video streams that I create...
For example
ffmpeg -i {file} -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144,setsar=sar=1/1
  -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 scale=-2:240,setsar=sar=1/1 
  -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"
  -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
  -dash_segment_type auto
  -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10
  -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
  -f dash /mkv_f/dash.mpd

One input file, it is necessary to get several video streams at the output. Each of which should have SAR 1:1, and DAR adapt (automatically).
Tried converting to separate files in 144/240 resolutions and setsar=sar=1/1. It works, but when you need to convert to several pots. Doesn't allow you to set the parameter setsar=sar=1/1
Conflicting stream aspect ratios values in Adaptation Set 1. Please ensure all adaptation sets have the same aspect ratio
[out#0/dash @ 0x558afdf4b9c0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Error sending frames to consumers: Invalid argument
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vf#0:1 @ 0x558afdf76d40] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)

How to set setsar=sar=1/1 on all video streams? And DAR will be set automatically...

According to the following and the following posts, all videos in the same adaptation set must have the same PAR (Pixel Aspect Ratio).
PAR=DAR/SAR, and applying setsar=1, results different PAR attributes.
The solution is creating an seperate adaptation set for each video stream.
The following answer does't give an error message, but not working...
According to @flex comment, the solution is defining id=0 to all of the streams:
Replace -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" with:
-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0 id=0,streams=1 id=0,streams=2"


Note:
The solution applies 3 streams (two videos, and one audio).
In case the input file has an audio stream, add -map 0:a:0.
Without audio, use -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0 id=0,streams=1"

Thanks, is there a universal option?
There will be one audio track, and an unknown number of video streams.
There can be 2, 5, 10 video streams
It is not advisable to programmatically assemble the line for -adaptation_sets

It doesn't work, the player doesn't see the streams, they are broken, not grouped. Is it possible to group them?

Only the first one sees id=0, streams=0 id=0, streams=1 id=0, streams=2 Having specified the ID, it also did not group

Great.. I updated the answer according to your comment. As you can see, my knowledge of mpeg-dash is very limited. I saw that there is no error message, and assumed that the streams are going to work. About the "universal option", maybe it suppose to work without -adaptation_sets. The default is ungrouped with id="0", id="1", id="2".
